# How to insert - after 6th character and after 8th character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events

Hello everyone and my problem faced is when user key in Malaysian Identity Card "930402084401", I want the key in number to automatically add - to become "930402-08-4401".

When User key in 930402084401

What I want in my textbox => 930402-08-4401

I try to refer to the code where the code will automatically add space every 4 numbers, but I totally have no idea how to change the code.

```js
document.getElementById('creditSpace').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var target = e.target,
    position = target.selectionEnd,
    length = target.value.length;

  target.value = target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
  target.selectionEnd = position += ((target.value.charAt(position - 1) === ' ' && target.value.charAt(length - 1) === ' ' && length !== target.value.length) ? 1 : 0);
});
```

```html
<label><input id="creditSpace"> CC Details </label>
```

Hope someone can solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of copying the code from someone else try to find your own solution. With _"add space every 4 numbers"_ a simple `for` loop would be a good starting point.

Comment: You also can use regular expressions' capture groups, and `\d{n}` to match `n` digits (i.e. `\d{6}` for matching 6 digits).

Comment: You have enough sample code to play around with. Just fool around with the `replace` function and you'll get a feel for how it works. You already know that it inserts a place at every 4th position so it should be easy enough to hack at that number to come up with the code that you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = '930402084401';
var t = s.replace( /(\d{6})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3' ); // 930402-08-4401
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple for loop:

```
let str = '930402084401';
const myFunc = str => {
  let r = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    r += str[i];
    if (i == 5 || i == 7) r += '-';
  }
  return r;
};
myFunc(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this. Use `map`, `slice` and `join`

```js
const format = (str, last = 0) =>
  [6, 2, 4].map((num) => str.slice(last, (last += num))).join("-");

const str = "930402084401";

console.log(format(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is also the simplest, just create separate groups of numbers and add in the `-` as necessary. If you want 6, 2, 4, then:

```js
const key = '930402084401';
const text = `${key.slice(0, 6)}-${key.slice(6, 8)}-${key.slice(8)}`;
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Str = "930402084401";
formattedStr = Str.slice(-Str.length, 6) + "-" + Str.slice(-6,-4) + "-" + Str.slice(-4)
console.log(formattedStr);
```